# Which version of Python is used for schemacrawler

Tags: python, schemacrawler

SchemaCrawler says it supports python, but it does not reference whether it support 2.7 or 3.5.

This link references Python in the fourth paragraph:
http://sualeh.github.io/SchemaCrawler/

What version of python does it support?

Comment: Where does it say it supports python? I see only java.

Comment: Looking [here](https://github.com/sualeh/SchemaCrawler/blob/2df132933c19f473f23f30fad82c0faef082a603/schemacrawler-distrib/src/site/resources/_downloader/python_ivy.xml#L8), I'm guessing it's 2.7.

Comment: Why did this get down voted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SchemaCrawler](http://sualeh.github.io/SchemaCrawler/) uses the [Jython](http://www.jython.org/index.html) library for Python support. As of this writing, [Jython](http://www.jython.org/index.html) supports Python 2.7. See the [Jython FAQs](https://wiki.python.org/jython/JythonFaq/GeneralInfo).

Sualeh Fatehi, [SchemaCrawler](http://sualeh.github.io/SchemaCrawler/)